# Dojo data grid to Excel file

Tags: php, excel, spreadsheet, dojox.grid

I have a question about exporting dojo data grid to excel file. I have made it work with csv file using the dojo exporter and some php code. However, how do I make it to save as excel file. I now about pear and some other libraries, but there has to be similar solution to the one I am using for the csv. Also, when I create my own exporter in dojo, does it need to have something more specific then  the code I am using for the csv exporter. Also, what do I need to change in the php code to make it save as xls. The code is below. Thanks a lot in advance.

My dojo exporter:

```
function exportCsv(){
    var g = dijit.byId("grid");
    g.exportGrid("csv",{
                writerArgs: {
                    separator: ","
                }
                }, function(str){


                        var form = document.createElement('form');
                        dojo.attr(form, 'method', 'POST');
                        document.body.appendChild(form);
                        dojo.io.iframe.send({
                                url: "csv.php",
                                form: form,
                                method: "POST",
                                content: {exp: str},
                                timeout: 15000
                        });
                        document.body.removeChild(form);

                        }); 
}
```

My php code working with csv:

```
<?

$time = time();
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"grid_$time.csv\"");
$exportedData = $_POST['exp'];


echo stripslashes($exportedData);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean? .csv **is** an excel file, or at last the data can be loaded into excel.. Is your question in reality, asking how to convert .csv to .xls?

Comment: While csv is workable in excel is not the same file. The user case is that if I have the excel incoming to my program; I can’t just change the file extension as I wish. I still have to figure out how to input the excel file to, but this is another meter.  May be if there is a service that will convert the csv to xls and then prompts the user for save…

Comment: this is not suitable for a javascript engine, however possible to some extent. Instead figure out the csv2xls process, see answer with a suitable class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice PHP tool, well suited for the purpose.

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1919-PHP-Stream-wrapper-to-read-and-write-MS-Excel-files.html

The setup is quite simple, you have most of it setup to passthrough the .csv file as download attachment allready, try the following code.

#### Conversion of CSV to XLS

First setup files csv-data and classes

```
require_once "excel.php"; 
define('_CSV_SEPARATOR_', ',');
// the excel class setsup xlsfile stream writer, point it to a tmp file
$export_file = "xlsfile://tmp/example.xls"; 
// the csv-contents must be put into an array, 
// serialized and sent to the stream
$import_file = "/path/to/CSV_FILE.csv";
$import=explode("\n", file_get_contents($import_file));
// column names should be first line
$header = array_shift($import);
```

Making sure, everything is looking nicely

```
$header = explode(_CSV_SEPARATOR_, $header);
for($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++)
    $header[$i] = trim($header[$i]);
```

Looping lines in remaining contents of csv-data

```
// rest of text is data, split em up and list them with array indices,
// and associative names as key in the rowdata
$assocData = array();

foreach($import as $line) {
   $row = explode(_CSV_SEPARATOR_, $line);
   $rowData = array();
   $unknowncount = 0;
   for($i = 0; $i < count($row); $i++) {
       if(!empty($header[$i])) $column = $header[$i];
       else $column = 'UNK'.$unknowncount++;

       $rowData[$column] = trim($row[$i]);
   }
   $assocData[]=$rowData;
}
```

Now, we write data to the export tmp-file and conversion is done

```
$fp = fopen($export_file, "wb"); 
if (!is_resource($fp)) 
{ 
    die("Cannot open $export_file"); 
} 
fwrite($fp, serialize($assocData)); 
fclose($fp);
```

#### Throughputting the outputted tmp-file to client

```
$export_file = "xlsfile://tmp/example.xls"; 
header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT"); 
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header ("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel"); 
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($export_file) . "\"" ); 
header ("Content-Description: PHP/INTERBASE Generated Data" ); 
readfile($export_file); 
exit;
```

Good luck and enjoy :D

Comment: Thanks for the response, it is a good starting point. I will let you know guys if it works.